# How to set up the video size so that it works on all ios devices without black bars

Tags: ios, video

I'm just wondering what size the video should be so that there won't be black bars on iphone 4/5 or ipad? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can't. 4" and 5" don't have screen with the same ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the iPhone 4, iPhone 5, and iPad all have different screen *aspect ratios* it's impossible to have a single size of video which in full-screen mode won't have black bars on some devices.

Instead, you can use the `scalingMode` property of `MPMoviePlayerController` to keep your video zoomed in to fit the screen (assuming that's what you're using to play back your video - similar analogues exist in other video playback classes). You probably want to use the `MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill` scaling mode, which will fill the video to fit the screen without distorting it.

Comment: It works! But the only problem is part of the video is inevitably cut off. The video I'm using right now fits the ipad. Maybe I should try one fit the iphone 5. Thanks anyway!